# Reducing image size (further) with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image-resizing

I am using the below code to reduce the size of my image. It works fine. My problem is, a 3MB picture will scale down to 470~ KB. Is there a way to reduce the file size even further? I played with all possible settings regarding interpolationmode, smoothingmode and the others but the resulting image is still around 400 kb. These images are used in a newspaper website and therefore should preserve their qualities too.

---

EDIT 
My image dimensions are 4000 x 3000 pixels and I am scaling down to 650 px wide.

---

```
Dim image_p As Image = _
    ResizeImage(img, Convert.ToInt32(pWidth), Convert.ToInt32(pHeight))

Private Function ResizeImage( _
    original_img As Bitmap, width As Integer, height As Integer) As Bitmap
        Dim callback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf GetThumbAbort)

        Dim new_img As New Bitmap(original_img, width, height) 'new blank bitmap'

        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(new_img)

        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
        g.CompositingQuality = _
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighSpeed
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver
        g.DrawImage(original_img, 0, 0, width, height)
        Return new_img
End Function
```

Comment: What does "These images are used in a newspaper website and therefore should preserve their qualities too" mean?  Preserve what?

Comment: What file format are you using?  Do you have an example image?  What are the full dimensions and colour depth? 650x?x?

Comment: @Will image format is jpg. Regarding what I ment; I cannot afford low quality compression as these images will be used on the front page of the web site.. (when I say these, All photos uploaded to the site are about 3MB. I scale them down to 650 x 300 (using cropping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale down the size if you use the [Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx) method that have the EncoderParametres option.

Just a part of the code from the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
 'Save the bitmap as a JPEG file with quality level 50.
 myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, CType(50L, Int32))
 myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
 myBitmap.Save("Shapes050.jpg", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)
```

Note: The other parameters that you use they affect the composition of the image, not the final size when you make it jpg. They affect the size in a manner of the quality, the higher the sharpness the higher the size because jpeg need to show more details, but the final size is change by that call I have here.